# Java XML transformer - Retain comments in output

Tags: java, xml

I need to modify a XML file but all the comments were trimmed in the output. I searched and think I need to use the Transformer.setProperty() fucntion but don't know know how to use it. Any help or hint will be very much appreciated. Please go easy on me on XML terminology because I am a XML newbie.

Thanks,

Below if the part that I want to keep, starting from the beginning of the XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ProductDataeXchangePackage [
<!-- DTD for IPC-2571
 Public Identifier: "-//IPC//DTD 2571 200111//EN"
 Official Location: http://webstds.ipc.org/2571.dtd -->

<!ELEMENT AdditionalAttribute EMPTY>

<!ATTLIST AdditionalAttribute  name        CDATA  #REQUIRED
                           value       CDATA  #REQUIRED
                           dimension   CDATA  #IMPLIED
                           dataType       (String | 
                                           Boolean | 
                                           Float | 
                                           Double | 
                                           Decimal | 
                                           DateTime | 
                                           Binary | 
                                           UriReference | 
                                           Other )  #IMPLIED
                             dataTypeOther CDATA  #IMPLIED
                             description CDATA  #IMPLIED >
<!ELEMENT AdditionalAttributes (AdditionalAttribute+)>
]>

<?pdx_version 1.0?>
<?generated_by Oracle/Extract/9.3.4/63?>
.....
```

Here is my code which re-write it to another file:

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = null;
try {
    trans = transfac.newTransformer();
    -->trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "??")<-- ;
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
try {
    trans.transform(source, result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String xmlString = sw.toString();
OutputStream f0;
byte buf[] = xmlString.getBytes();
f0 = new FileOutputStream("pdx1.xml");
for(int n=0;n<buf.length;n++) {
    f0.write(buf[n]);
}
f0.close();
buf = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

A DTD is not part of the XSLT/XPath data model so it is not preserved by an XSLT transformation. There are some ways around it but they depend on certain tools or extensions. As you use Java and only a default transformer to serialize some DOM tree you might first want to check whether `LSSerializer` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) is not doing a better job than a default `Transformer` to output the DTD and/or CDATA section nodes.

Comment: Thanks Martin, for the info. I will take a look on the LSSerializer but in the mean time, in order to meet the deadline, I guess I will just do it the old fashion way - using file operation to inject the DTD section back into the output file.